# how to disable contextmenu of flashcanvas

Tags: flot, flashcanvas

I'm using FlashCanvas ([flashcanvas](http://flashcanvas.net)) instead of excanvas.js library to draw Flot chart in IE7/8 versions. I'm able to view the charts successfully but not able to disable the right click (context menu) option. As mentioned in their Documention section under configuration [falsh canvas configuration documentation](http://flashcanvas.net/docs/config) im having below code at the bottom of the page, but still contextMenu is coming up when i'm right-clicking. what is the mistake im doing here

```
if (typeof FlashCanvas != "undefined") {
    FlashCanvas.setOptions({
        disableContextMenu: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using the free or pro version of FlashCanvas? The [FlashCanvas Configuration Documentation](http://flashcanvas.net/docs/config) states "You can configure FlashCanvas Pro...", and [this google group post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/flashcanvas/NkRaFYhXXAM/m5KE3_GJFiYJ) states "Currently, only FlashCanvas Pro users can configure the options..."

Comment: @prmech thanks for the reply, im using free version.. may be thats the reason